# Incompatible pointer type Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've pulled out this project and started working on it again, i'm getting an error on the following;

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView*)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker*)marker
{
    CustomInfoWindow *InfoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return InfoWindow;
}
```

> Incompatible pointer types returning 'CustomInfoWindow *' from a function with result type 'UIView *'

Comment: what's the type of `CustomInfoWindow`?

Comment: What is the @interface for `CustomInfoWindow`? The error message indicates that it is not a subclass of UIView.

Comment: @interface CustomInfoWindow : UIViewController

For google maps inside the viewcontroller

Comment: A view controller subclass should be named `SomethingViewController`. It avoids a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
 CustomInfoWindow *InfoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
return InfoWindow.view;
```

you are returning viewcontroller which wrong because function's return type is UIView type
so, please return viewcontroller's view.
update your code with this and try

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the document whether we can use above like that?

If you use like above it shows the error

> because it must return UIView

[Google Map iOS Document Says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#ae1614978aef680d671a6a95da8e13bf7)

> ***markerInfoWindow*** called when a marker is about to become selected, and
>   provides an optional custom info window to use for that marker if this
>   method **returns a UIView**.
>
> If you change this view after this method is
>   called, those changes will not necessarily be reflected in the
>   rendered version.
>
> **The returned UIView must not have bounds greater
>   than 500 points on either dimension.**
>
> **As there is only one info window
>   shown at any time, the returned view may be reused between other info
>   windows.**
>
> Removing the marker from the map or changing the map's
>   selected marker during this call results in undefined behavior.